# Failed to Read Session Data After Renaming DB

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, session, error-handling

Joomla 3.9.11

Working on localhost, today I decided to rename my database from `dbtest` to `dbnew`. I did this using HeidiSQL > rename db

When I visit my site I now see the following error;

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path:
>   C:\xampp\tmp) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\libraries\joomla\session\handler\native.php on
>   line 260 Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the
>   session

I opened `configuration.php` and replaced all instances of `dbtest` with 'dbnew' but same thing.

I've also emptied the db sessions table, tried a different browser and restarted apache / mysql.

If I revert the name back to `dbtest` and change my `configuration.php` accordingly all works as expected. SO, what am I doing wrong, how can I change my db name correctly?

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

When I renamed the database I also had to re-assign the database user to this database.

Answer (score 0):

First check your session handler in configuration.php and try to set it to 'none'.

```
$session_handler = 'none';
```

That should work in most cases and you might get some information on the true causes of the failure.

In my case, the `$session_handler` was set to 'database' and I had an error in my database setup. If this applies to you as well, check your database setup carefully again (host, db, user & password).

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour].